# Weird file format while saving files

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, download

On Windows 10, Acer Aspire E 15

Whenever I download a pdf file, in the prompt comes up to ask where I want to save it, in the file type, I get some gibberish. This is an example.

[image]

However, the file does open as a pdf. Any idea on why this is happening and a possible fix?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Here is another example - (the save as is different even though I'm saving a pdf both the times)

[image]

Comment: just to be sure, this is for any PDF from any website?  or just this site?

Comment: Don't know if it's true for **any** website, but true for the ones I frequently use [here](https://imgur.com/nU2IhbT) is another example when I try to download from arxiv

Comment: find out.  this matters.

Comment: How do I find out from "any" website? (there are millions of them out there) I've tried it out again for 5-6 sites, and I get similar results

Comment: As per the OP's statement, this problem is not related to any particular site anymore. It is some problem in the windows system of OP

Comment: Have you at any point used an alternate language?

Comment: that was my first thought too, I did, use another language, but not the one that comes up in save-as type. Another point I'd like to bring up is that for a .pdf file, I get different texts everytime (refer to edit)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Open `regedit` and navigate to `HKCR\.pdf`. Make note of what the `(Default)` entry value is. For example, if you have Adobe Reader it might say `AcroExch.Document`.

Now, navigate to `HKCR\<name of default value>`, so in my example above I would navigate to `HKCR\AcroExch.Document`.

See what the value for the `(default)` key is. This is where your corruption should be. You can change it to something more familiar like `Adobe Acrobat Document`. Or use whatever identifier you want to use, depending on what application it is that is opening the PDFs.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was due to a corrupt pdf reader I'd used in the past, but later uninstalled!

Comment: @DDDAD Since this looks like a Far Eastern language (Chinese?) string to me, I would be bothered if the corrputed PDF reader was more a sort of malware and thus pay attention to other anomalites on the system.

Comment: @rexkogitans the first image looks like Urdu, but I'm not sure. The second one is Korean.

Comment: @AndrewT. and if you ask me it's probably just outputting the memory reference as a rendering of whatever encoding system (was it ANSI-8? UTF-8?) that the Windows OS uses, which may hit on random characters anywhere

Comment: @psosuna windows is primarily UTF-16

Comment: @rexkogitans, thanks for the suggestion. The pdf reader was a good one with no known history of malware. However, there were some errors while uninstalling it which may have led to the error